# How to animate background color on ElevatedButton?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to create a fade between two background colors when my ElevatedButton change his state to disable, how can I do that ?

```
final _buttonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
  animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 0),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
);
```

I see there is an animationDuration property, however it seems to only create a delay between the change of color. No animations are visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `AnimatedSwitcher` . First define this out of build method:

```
bool isVisible = false;
```

then do this:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            key: UniqueKey(),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isVisible = !isVisible;
                });
              },
              child: Text('click'),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
                  overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                  (states) {
                    return states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)
                        ? Colors.grey
                        : null;
                     },
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                      isVisible ? Colors.red : Colors.green)),
            ),
          ),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be working however, If I want to change the size of the button using SizedBox for example, the animation seems to be cancelled.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. you should pass the key to AnimatedSwitcher's child. this is very important part.

Comment: Thanks this is working great ! I changed the styling to ElevatedButton.styleFrom, and now the disabledBackgroundColor property is working with animation !

Comment: I updated my answer, to add ripple effect.

Comment: It worths mention that it's better replace `UniqueKey` with a key based on an updated property: `Key(isVisible.toString())`. This way we can avoid unnecessary transitions on rebuild.

Comment: thanks @AndreyGordeev, yeah that would helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can achieve similar behavior without `ElevatedButton` is like so, by using `AnimatedContainer` and `InkWell`

```
//define a state variable
bool disableButton = false;

//build the button like so
InkWell(
  onTap: disableButton ? null : () => print('Button tapped'),
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: disableButton ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 6),
    child: Text('Abc'),
  ),
)

//make disableButton true to disable the button
setState(() => disableButton = true);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have the same nice ripple effect as ElevatedButton ?