# How can I change the background and text color of a textbutton in flutter, in a single line?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

most Easy Way to add a BackGroundColor to Textbutton

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red),
),
```

BUT,
I also want to change text color:

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            textColor: Colors.white, 
            backgroundColor: Colors.red),
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change `textColor` with `TextButton` Style. you can do that with `child` widget like this:

```
 TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
        'click',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: But how can i achieve background color in ElevatedButtons?
styleFrom dont seem to have  backgroundColor property

Comment: @SaadMansoor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658052/10306997) I said how you can change ElevatedButtons background color.